# Abp.AspNetCore.OData override the route path

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am just configuring a new OData project using this package.
I have configured the project as per the documentation https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration

But I am looking to override the default route.

Instead of `/odata`
I would like `/odata/v2` as the default.

I've had a look into the MapAction method in the Modules PreInitialize override, but I am unsure how to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's stated in [AbpWebApiODataModuleConfiguration](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.Web.Api.OData/WebApi/OData/Configuration/AbpWebApiODataModuleConfiguration.cs#L22) class. You can override `MapAction` and set `routePrefix`to `/odata/v2`